# can you help me to transform forall FO logical formula to it equivalent not exist formula?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

i have this formula

`∀x ∀y (A(x,y) V  A(y,x)  → B(y,c1) ∧ B(x,c2) ∧ c1≠c2`)

to the equivalent formula that by using existential quantifier
  ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about mathematics.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about logic and [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`∀x ∀y X` is the same as `¬∃(x, y) ¬X`

'X → Y' is the same as 'There is no counterexample when X but not Y'

`¬(A(x,y) V  A(y,x)  → B(x,c1) ∧ B(x,c2) ∧ c1≠c2)` = `(A(x,y) V  A(y,x)) ∧ ¬(B(x,c1) ∧ B(x,c2) ∧ c1≠c2))` - our counterexample. If we put negation of the second part in it and collect everything together, we get:

`¬∃(x, y) (A(x,y) V A(y,x)) ∧ (¬B(x,c1) v ¬B(x,c2) v c1 = c2)`

Update: replaced `¬∃x ¬∃ y` with `¬∃(x, y)`. I suppose that's what you originally meant, right?

Comment: No it's not. `∀x ∀y X` is the same as `¬∃x ∃y ¬X`, but `¬∃x ¬∃y ¬X` is something _completely_ different.

Comment: What's the syntax for 'there exists no x and y for which ...'?
I suppose `¬∃(x,y)` would be self-explanatory and the question will have no solution then (or, rather, question would be fixed too)

Comment: x @Daerdemandt: I believe what you're looking for is exactly "¬∃x ∃y ¬X" -- which says "it is not the case that there exists x such that there exists y such that X is false". Note that the ¬ negates the _entire formula_ that comes after it -- that is, "∃x ∃y ¬X"; it would make no syntactic sense to negate the quantifier alone; "∃x" is not a formula but merely an unary operator.

Comment: Looks a bit confusing though. Is speaking about counterexample pair `(x, y)` valid too?

Comment: x @Daerdemandt: It will most likely be understood alright, but it is not really standard notation.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to make that change, you basically want to find the opposite of what the inner statement says , because if a statement is true **for every ** x, then it means the opposite of it does not happen, ever;  not exist means just that, there is no x such that makes the statement true.